# In VS Code, how can I get the path to the currently selected Python?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-python

I want to specify the Python path in `tasks.json` without an explicit full path. I used to do this using `python.pythonPath`, but that setting is now deprecated. What is the alternative way to retrieve the currently selected Python path? Are there any other VS Code environment variables?

Comment: seems like `python.venvPath` / `python.defaultInterpreterPath`, [look](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/settings-reference)

Answer (score 1):

For the current python path, you need to select an interpreter and the currently used one is shown as a relative path in the box.

[image: Current Python Path]

In tasks, have args called options so you can define env and  PYTHONPATH there

[image: args call]

You can find more details about tasks from the [Tasks in Visual Studio Code](https://nam04.safelinks.protection.outlook.com/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fcode.visualstudio.com%2Fdocs%2Feditor%2Ftasks%23_custom-tasks&data=04%7C01%7Cmdashikur%40wicresoft.com%7C1a4fa62fdcc74aecc80d08d96c595bcb%7C05baf3e556fb496e9c41692c065323a4%7C1%7C0%7C637659953356672961%7CUnknown%7CTWFpbGZsb3d8eyJWIjoiMC4wLjAwMDAiLCJQIjoiV2luMzIiLCJBTiI6Ik1haWwiLCJXVCI6Mn0%3D%7C1000&sdata=qxKzaR5x85%2BQAgrniqr4hK9h0JNNGPG0IXdhD0rU%2B6g%3D&reserved=0) documentation.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the Python VSCode extension installed, and an interpreter is selected, then you can get the path to that interpreter in tasks.json using `${command:python.interpreterPath}`.

Answer (score -2):

You can open VS Code command selector with `ctrl + shift + p` and type "Python: Select Interpreter" to open a dropdown menu of all available interpreters. Doing this should create the appropriate entry to `settings.json` (which was `python.pythonPath` for me with version Python plugin version v2021.8.1159798656)

You can also change the interpreter from the bottom toolbar.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, OP needs a variable that can be used in the `tasks.json` file (or any other, I guess) that holds the path of the currently selected interpreter through that toolbar. `python.pythonPath` does not hold that value.