# What is the alternative to python.pythonPath in settings.json?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-python

In a Python tutorial I'm following, the Python path is linked to the `python.pythonPath` setting in the `settings.json` file of Visual Studio Code. However, the `python.pythonPath` does not exist anymore.

I tried to find the `python.pythonPath` variable or alternatives in the default `settings.json` file, but I could not find one.

What is the alternative to this settings variable?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In VSCode, how can I get the path of currently selected Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68993358/in-vscode-how-can-i-get-the-path-of-currently-selected-python)

Answer (score 2):

According to the [documentation on Github](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/wiki/Setting-descriptions#pythondefaultinterpreterpath), the `python.pythonPath` setting is indeed not used anymore.

Instead, a new settings with the name `python.defaultInterpreterPath` has been introduced.

Note, however, that this setting is not *exactly* the same. The way it is processed by Visual Studio Code is changed as well. See the documentation linked above, or the [Python settings reference](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/settings-reference):

> `python.defaultInterpreterPath`:
>
> Path to the default Python interpreter to be used by the Python extension on the first time it loads for a workspace, or the path to a folder containing the Python interpreter.
> Can use variables like `${workspaceFolder}` and `${workspaceFolder}/.venv`.
> Using a path to a folder allows anyone working with a project to create an environment in the `.venv` folder as appropriate to their operating system, rather than having to specify an exact platform-dependent path. The `settings.json` file can then be included in a source code repository.
>
> **Note:** Changes to this setting made after an interpreter has been selected for a workspace will not be applied or considered by the Python extension. The Python extension doesn't automatically add or change this setting.